# A bunch of selfies

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

The puzzle below represents commonly used...?

---

**Instructions:**

*a)* Trust your eyes, forget the rest.

```
S Y R Y S T T
a C f f C b R
S f Y f S R T
R w a b R T w
S b Y w S b a
a C f b C a w
```

*b)* Match.

```
 =_=|
```

---

Comment: (link URL is a potential spoiler) I think I may have just found a [weird coincidence](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fYSYC.png)

Comment: @LukasRotter What coincidence do you see?

Comment: @VarunW. rot13(Vs lbh ybbx ng nyy gur ybpngvbaf bs F, L, P naq s, lbh pna qenj gur pbeerfcbaqvat yrggre ol pbaarpgvat gubfr abqrf (n "frysvr"). Nf n fvqrabgr, E naq o jbhyq xvaq bs jbex jvgu ebgngvbaf naq nqqvat fxrgpul yvarf. V gubhtug gung {o} zvtug cbvag gb na vzthe hey (jvgu '=' orvat gur fnzr yrggre gjvpr), fb V gevrq nyy 24 pbzovangvbaf naq gur yvaxrq cvp vf gur bayl uvg V sbhaq, juvpu pbvapvqragnyyl vf n cvp jvguva gur FR argjbex.)

Comment: @LukasRotter rot13(Gung vf cbffvoyl gur zbfg **penml** pbvapvqrapr va FgnpxRkpunatr uvfgbel, vs gur vzntr vf abg gur nafjre)

Comment: @LukasRotter Completely coincidental :) But you're correct! "Selfie" refers to exactly what you found. Now it's a matter of making sense of step 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer here is:

> **CURRENCIES**!

To understand how, first of all consider the grid of letters, as there are four 'selfies' hidden within it:

> i.e. There are four large letters that can be drawn out by doing a dot-to-dot puzzle involving every occurrence of that same letter in the grid: **Y, f, C and S**
>
>  [image: Selfies discovered]

Next comes part (b) - we have to match each of the four symbols to one of the 'selfies' we have just found. This is how we should do it in order to obtain a relevant solution:

> 'Y' with '='
>  'f' with '_'
>  'C' with '='
>  'S' with '|'

Why? Because:

> by overlaying these letters and symbols, we obtain further symbols that represent **the four [most traded currencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Most_traded_currencies)** in the world:
>
>  'Y' with '=' → ¥ (Japanese **Yen**)
>  'f' with '_' → £ (British **Pound**)
>  'C' with '=' → € (Eurozone **Euro**)
>  'S' with '|' → $ (US **Dollar**)

Comment: wow. Stiv the sleuth! I had long given up on that puzzle. haha

Comment: @JLee Was clearing some random files from my desktop and found one containing the first step to this (after which I'd clearly got stuck), and somehow the second step came to me in a flash this time! And now back to work...!

Comment: I don't get the "selfies" reference though

Comment: @JLee That's relevant to the first step - the smaller letters contribute to their own large self-portraits...

Comment: No need for a hint on this one either then! Great job!  And yes, the "selfie" was only relevant to step 1, as a guide.